# How to hook and run function inside event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set-up in javascript/jquery to hook specific function in certain event like how the wordpress action hook works

Basic code

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-modal]', function() {
    var dis = $(this).data('modal');
    // how can I hook something in here from outside this file
    $('#'+dis).addClass('is-active');
    // I also want to hook and run a function in here without directly calling them
});
```

Something like below is what I'm trying to achieve

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-modal]', function() {
    var dis = $(this).data('modal');

    trigger('before_open_' + dis); // I don't know what method to use here

    $('#'+dis).addClass('is-active');

    trigger('after_open_' + dis); // I don't know what method to use here
});

// I don't also know how to properly initialize the event
$(document).on('before_open_classes_pop', function() {
    console.log( $(this).data('modal') );
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *wordpress action hook* What does this mean? Can you specify exactly what you want other than calling a method or triggering a custom event?

Comment: If you want to add your own customized event, check this out. https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) first

```
$( "[data-modal]" ).on( "before_open", function(){
   var dis = $(this).modal();
   //logic to handle the before open event for a specific dis here
});
```

and

```
$( "[data-modal]" ).on( "after_open", function(){
   var dis = $(this).modal();
   //logic to handle the after open event for a specific dis here
});
```

Now invoke these events as

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-modal]', function() {
    var dis = $(this).data('modal');
    $(this).trigger('before_open'); 
    $('#'+dis).addClass('is-active');
    $(this).trigger('after_open');
});
```

Comment: thanks, just what I'm looking for, I end up doing it like this ```$(this).trigger('before_open_' + dis, [$(this), dis]);``` :)